# My Ajax call. Always return error

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, magento

Hi guys i am working in magento and i have searched a lot but didn't get any solution this is my ajax

```
var $wk_jq = jQuery.noConflict();
  $wk_jq.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpmassuploadaddons/index/runProfiler'); ?>",
                type : 'GET',
                data : {id : profilerId,row : countOfStartedProfiles},
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(content) {
                    console.log('content success');

                },
                 error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(xhr);
                            console.log(textStatus);
                            console.log(errorThrown);
                        }
            });
```

I am getting parsererror always

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
responseText  "NULL\nNULL\n{"savedRows":1...":"successfully saved"}"
status  200
statusText  "OK"
```

even my php code is working fine and returning json encode string  `{"savedRows":1,"success":"successfully saved"}` with success message here is my php code

```
public function runProfilerAction() {
    ob_start();
    $profileId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $rowCount = $this->getRequest()->getParam('row');
    $profile = Mage::getModel('mpmassuploadaddons/profilesession')->load($profileId);
    if($profile->getproductType() == "simple") {
        $result = Mage::getModel('mpmassuploadaddons/mpmassupload')->importSimpleProducts($profileId,$rowCount);    
    } elseif($profile->getproductType() == "downloadable") {
        $result = Mage::getModel('mpmassuploadaddons/mpmassupload')->importDownloadableProducts($profileId,$rowCount);  
    } elseif($profile->getproductType() == "virtual") {
        $result = Mage::getModel('mpmassuploadaddons/mpmassupload')->importVirtualProducts($profileId,$rowCount);   
    } elseif($profile->getproductType() == "configurable") {
        $result = Mage::getModel('mpmassuploadaddons/mpmassupload')->importConfigurableProducts($profileId,$rowCount);   
    } 

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

This json  `{"savedRows":1,"success":"successfully saved"}` is also in correct format i have decode it here http://json.parser.online.fr/

and its fine please help thanks

Comment: console.log('content suxccess'); suxccess ??

Comment: Why ob_start() at the begining ? You can try ob_clean() if you want but it's not a solution.

Comment: Is your magento script prepending "NULL\nNULL\n" to your json string?

Comment: i have array 
Array
(
    [savedRows] => 1
    [success] => successfully saved
)
and i am using json_encode 

i am not appending any null in it

Comment: Well something is appending those. Either find out what's causing it on the php side or trim the null and newline caracters from the beginning with javascript.

Comment: on php side i am using json_encode method and sending this to ajax response

Comment: still getting same error with this code echo json_encode(trim($result));

Comment: also getting this error as well 
Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: as @Dontfeedthecode pointed out your code appears to be returning null appended..you might wanna check  your functions `importSimpleProducts` or whichever is executing to fix it.. & sorry
I meant `echo trim(json_encode($result)); exit;`

Comment: echo trim(json_encode($result)); exit; also getting same error by using this. My function i have checked my function its not appending any null ....

Comment: why you have `ob_start()` in the function?I do not see any use of it.. "NULL\nNULL\n" is coming from your model methods somewhere..I assume param 1 to be string error is not there..you can use the trim function to define which chars to strip using `character_mask` param

Comment: null is not coming from any where i have tested it if i use 
json_encode(array("savedRows"=>"1","success"=>"successfully saved"));


still getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this

```
ob_clean();
```

before `json_encode`

Hopefully it works...